# Overlay or popup with full screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my website, I have some images and iframe which I am displaying them inside a fancybox.

Everything is working ok, but now the requirement of the website is to have a fullscreen like the overlay screen in usatoday website.

http://www.usatoday.com/tech/

Note: When click on any article will shown that overlay.

The desired effect is when clicked will make full page overlay or popup. So I need good example to make it same.

Thanks

Comment: Use http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Comment: The question is unclear, are you asking how to use fancybox?

Comment: No i want some script not fancybox but same effect of the usatoday.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example for overlay, <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/FvaMF/)**</kbd>

```
(function($) {
  $('article').on('click', function() {
    if($('.overlay').length < 1) {
       $('body').append('<span class="overlay"></span>');
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click','.overlay', function() {
    $('.overlay').remove();   
  });
})(jQuery);
```

also include buttons in the events for open/close fancybox.

---

```
.overlay {
  background: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize iFrame from inner page than you will have to write your own logic.

First, create a function in your main page to resize Width and Height of iFrame. (i.e. the page with iFrame).

e.g.

```
function resetFrameSize(set_height, set_width){
    $("#frame_id_here").css('width',set_width);
    $("#frame_id_here").css('height',set_height);        
}
```

Than, from inner page. You can call this function in any page load function.

```
window.parent.resetFrameSize(new_height_value,new_width_value);
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old answer but there is a jquery plugin that does exactly the same. The plugin can be found [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/block)

Now coming to the usage part, it is pretty easy to use.

You have to make sure that jquery is pre loaded and then load this:

```
<script type="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
....
....
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#<BUTTON_ID>").click(function(){
        $.blockUI();

        setTimeout(function(){
           $.unblockUI(); 
        }, 2000);
     });
   });
</script>
```

*FYI:* The code is pretty basic.

Hope this helps.